# Csv import with split lines

Tags: python-3.x, csv, import, split

Hello I'm pretty much new to python.
I´m trying to import a csv file into a list and then split the lines but get the error:
new_list = your_list.split(',') 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

```
import csv

with open('testcsv.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  your_list = list(reader)
for row in your_list:
  new_list = your_list.split(',')
```

CSV file:

```
1,11
2,12
3,13
4,14
```

The output I would like from the list is:

```
'1', '11'
'2', '12'
'3', '13'
'4', '14'
```

Now I get:

```
'1, 11' 
'2, 12' and so on...
```

Comment: Split `row`, not `your_list`.

Comment: I get the same error if I change your_list to row
    import csv

    with open('testcsv.csv', 'r') as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f)
      your_list = list(reader)
    for row in your_list:
      new_list = row.split(',')

Comment: Hmm how do I format the code in a comment?

Comment: Can I ask what's the final result that you want from your CSV file? I just executed your code locally and it fails because `your_list` will end up with something like `[['row1a', 'row1b'], ['row2a', 'row2b']]`, and `split` cannot be called on arrays

Comment: Ok that explains the error, I want it split into two colums thanks.

Comment: Or rather I want to import a csv file and want all strings in one row that are separated with a ',' split into a new coulmn

Comment: Could you edit into your question exactly what kind of output you're looking for? Sorry I'm a bit confused

Comment: Does @anvita surapaneni have what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your_list has your solution. You do not need to perform any further steps.

```
with open('testcsv.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  your_list = list(reader)
  print your_list
```

result: [['1', '11'], ['2', '12'], ['3', '13'], ['4', '14']]

Comment: Yes thanks thats exactly how I want it, so now I just need to write each row into a list, not just print each row, like this (that does not work) in the for loop last_list[row] = new_list

Comment: Do you mean add all of the items into a single list?

Comment: Yes a single list but each ',' on each row separated in a new column

Comment: like a list of list?

Comment: Well I´m not sure I understand how you mean but I would like your result above, if I write `print new_list` outside the for loop

Comment: you could just do a  print your_list

Comment: Yes you are right???, I must have missunderstood the results when I was experimenting at first, so my problem was actually not a problem :/
Thank yu very much for your help.

Comment: No problem.. I will edit the solution too so that you can approve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

@excaza made the right observation in the comments, you should be using modifying `row` and not `your_list`. But I think you're looking for `join` instead?

```
for row in your_list:
  string_row = ', '.join(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

So as anvita pointed out the problem was not a problem, the result was what I wanted from the begining just using:

```
with open('testcsv.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  your_list = list(reader)
  print your_list
```

So I dont know if the hole thread should be deleted as its somewhat confusing?

However, I managed to solve the problem (that was no problem) with this code :)

```
import csv

with open('testcsv.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)
a = []
for row in your_list:
    string_row = ', '.join(row)
    new_list = string_row.split(',')
    a.append(new_list)
print(a)
```